# Apache2 virtualhost configuration trouble

Tags: apache, virtualhost

This is my situation:

I have Redmine and Gitlab in my server which does not have a domain associated, because I will use the server IP address.

I want to configure two virtualhosts in apache2 with SSL in order to serve the above web applications, so I can access them like this:

```
https://x.y.z/redmine
```

which is located in /var/www/

```
https://x.y.z/gitlab
```

located in /home/git/github/public

I have configured apache by enabling two files in site-enabled: github.vhost and gitlab.vhost. The problem is that I cannot set gitlab to be accessible with

```
https://x.y.z/github
```

but only in

```
https://x.y.z
```

probably beacuse I do not use a domain but only the IP address of the server, and I don't know exactly how to manage it.

I would need some suggestion on how to correctly set the two vhost files.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Any description of the problem you want to share? We are not mind readers. Until then, the only way to get help is by providing a detailed description of the problem.

Comment: I tried to make it more clear, hope it is clear enough now. I don't want to copy/past the vhost files I have since they are long and probably wrong, so I though it would be better for me to rewrite them from scratch with your suggestions and some good simple example.

Comment: This is my apachectl -S out http://pastebin.com/ShgYHG3h

Comment: For lack of information regarding your configuration, it is impossible to find the root cause of your issue. I can only refer you to read the documentations. Hope this helps. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html